# How to properly type an array of enum entries?

Tags: typescript, enums, typing

I have a basic `enum` below:

```
export enum Fruit {
   apple,
   banana
}
```

I want to export a fixed `Array` of the `enum` *keys*

```
export const Fruits = Object.entries(Fruit).map(f => f[0]);
```

Which should give, as desired, `['apple', 'banana']` and `Fruits` *typed* as `string[]`.

In an attempt for a more specific *typing*, I added `as keyof typeof Fruit` like so

```
 export const Fruits = Object.entries(Fruit).map(f => f[0] as keyof typeof Fruit);
```

Which gives me the *type* `const Fruits: ("apple" | "banana")[]`. **Is this the most that I can get?**

I was aiming to get a *typing* like `const Fruits: ["apple", "banana"] = ....` which I think is the perfect *typing* I should produce.

**Footnote:**

I wouldn't like to utilize the other method of defining `enum`s, Just for the sake of avoiding that redundancy,

```
export enum Fruit {
   apple = 'apple',
   banana = 'banana'
}
```

And I am happy to do something like:

```
interface Meal {
   fruit: keyof tpeof Fruit // since the default enum values are integers, use keys
}
```

So I'd be happy to have a solution that doesn't require me to do so. If there's no other way, do mention in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind that there is no guarantee that `Object.entries` or `Object.keys` preserve the order of keys. Hence you need to return a permutation of all possible states and not only `['apple', 'banana']`.

In this case it should be `['apple', 'banana'] | ['banana', 'apple']`.

```js
export enum Fruit {
    apple,
    banana
}

// credits goes to https://twitter.com/WrocTypeScript/status/1306296710407352321
type TupleUnion<U extends PropertyKey, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];

const keys = <
    Keys extends string,
    Obj extends Record<Keys, unknown>
>(obj: Obj) =>
    Object.keys(Fruit) as TupleUnion<keyof Obj>;

const result = keys(Fruit)

// ["apple", "banana"] | ["banana", "apple"]
type Check = typeof result
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGJWQS3gbwCg4S4BDMMAG2ABpjSAjMxFswgX0MJgE8xgcACrJqwAKqIcERAB5xCEDCQATAM5wAClAgDYvANLBetOACVFyxOvKJeAbQC6cALxwnAPldwipdwGU4HEQ4cUcALjgAURAAYypkFWB5U38vUCsbRGAAN2AoOAB%20dwA6MrNU50iRMUlpORj4xOTxVI9TezKSirh-Rw8Abk57MKHCWJk1eABrYw03WQYSI14NDNUNKahggHN6PwB5RgArSw3zYAmoFVkVtVNkRGnECAB3RA9CDwAKCBPIo7HACUrk%20hxOlxgJVmq2%20WFwMBBZA0NRodRkshhEAAZnBAYNuBNEFM4FBgGpkFR4G4YWo4dg8EDuAB6ZnuABEFDE7NM7OYrFY7OcAB8Ofy2Dy4JzKDQhTx%20IIAMIAC0u028fAEONJ5MpMCAA)
I have used `keys` instead of `entries` because we are interested only in keys.

[Here](https://catchts.com/union-array), in my blog, you can find more about convertiong union to tuples and [function arguments inference](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

So, which enum is better: with values as integers or strings?

First of all, enums has their own flaws.
COnsider this example:

```js
export enum Fruit {
    apple,
    banana
}
const fruit = (enm: Fruit) => {}

fruit(100) // ok, no error
```

Is it safe - no!

Enums with integers are got to use if you have a bit mask.

It is better to use enum with string values:

```js
export enum Fruit {
   apple = 'apple',
   banana = 'banana'
}
```

If you still want to use enum with integers, consider this example:

```js
const enum Fruit {
    apple,
    banana,
}

const fruit = (enm: typeof Fruit) => { }

fruit(100) // expected error

Object.keys(Fruit) // impossible
```

If you want to use enum with integers and `Object.keys/entries` you might want to use a **safest** approach:

```js
export const Fruit = {
    apple: 0,
    banana: 1,
} as const

const fruit = (enm: typeof Fruit) => { }

fruit(100) // expected safe
```

Comment: So the `const Fruits: ("apple" | "banana")[]` I already have would cover the concern of the order of keys, right? The only thing we don't have on that type is that it does not strictly say that all keys are in the array.

Comment: No exactly, because `("apple" | "banana")[]` might have a dublicates: `['apple','apple','banana']` - this is not what we want